# C variable assignment to array element

Tags: c, arrays, variables, reference

Quick question on how a variable is assigned the value of an array element. Trying to make sure my code uses minimal memory.

If I have a predefined array of structs and want to create a reference to one element of the array, how do I create the variable so that it's passed by reference as opposed to value? I've searched around for this but perhaps my search string isn't what it needs to be.

for instance

```
#myfile.h
typedef struct {
  uint8_t abba;
  uint8_t zabba;
} mystruct;

extern mystruct mystructs[2];

#myfile.c
mystruct mystructs[2] = {
  {.abba=0,.zabba=1},
  {.abba=2,.zabba=3}
};

void myfunc1() {
  mystruct ms1 = mystructs[1];
  printf("%d", ms1.abba);
  ms1.zabba = 5;
}

void myfunc2() {
  printf("%d", mystructs[1].abba);
  mystructs[1].zabba = 5;
}
```

So my questions are as follows:
When I create ms1 in myfunc1, is it just a reference to mystructs[1]? or does it copy the element into ms1?

Will myfunc1 and myfunc2 yield the same results in memory usage?

will ms1.zabba = 5 actually update mystructs[1].zabba?

Comment: If I could I would accept both Peter Schneider's and Quentin's answers. Peter details how it works, Quentin gives an example of creating ms1 as a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create ms1 in myfunc1, is it just a reference to mystructs[1]?

No, it's a copy.

> or does it copy the element into ms1?

Yes.

> Will myfunc1 and myfunc2 yield the same results in memory usage?

No. (To be more elaborate: myfunc1 creates a local object of type mystruct ("on the stack"); after leaving the function everything is back as before, so no harm done. The structs are not big, so no problem. On PCs you could get a problem with things that are big (MBs) or expensive (e.g. socket connections).)

> will ms1.zabba = 5 actually update mystructs[1].zabba?

No, since ms1 is a copy.

You may want to use pointers or references.

Answer (score 2):

It's a copy. You need to use a pointer to actually modify the remote struct :

```
void myfunc1() {
  mystruct *ms1 = &mystructs[1];
  printf("%d", ms1->abba);
  ms1->zabba = 5;
}
```

Comment: I initially tried this in my code but I got the warning. "#145-D a value of type "const mystruct *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "mystruct *" so I was assuming I did something wrong. The code compiles and seems to run as expected though.

Comment: Warnings are not to be taken lightly. But nothing in your question mentions that `mystructs` is `const`...

Comment: What Quentin says is true; that warning shouldn't happen. If you try to assemble a small working example (doesn't need main() for a compiler message!) we can see where it comes from. Will probably be obvious.

Comment: Played around with it a bit this morning. I was declaring/defining the mystructs array as: "extern const mystruct mystructs[2];" so initializing the pointer as const "const mystruct *ms1..." seemed to do the trick. I take it declaring const here will prevent me from doing "ms1->abba = 6;" and overwriting what should have been constant data.

Comment: @user3817250 Exactly.